# How does Azure AutoMLConfig parameter "validation_size" parameter select validation data from the training data?

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service

I am currently using Azure Automated Machine Learning to train a classification model and configuring it to select the validation and testing data from the training dataset. What is not clear is how the AutoML selects the subset data from any of the doco I can find online. Does it randomly select the validation and testing data or does it select the first/last x # of rows from the training dataset? The reason I would like to know is to see if it is potentially contributing to data leakage in my model.

I have found these references useful but dont provide an answer to my question: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-configure-cross-validation-data-splits?view=azureml-api-1), [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/ml/?view=azure-ml-py) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-train-automl-client/azureml.train.automl.automlconfig.automlconfig?view=azure-ml-py).